# CSS Remove border from Rectangular Box

Tags: css

I have created a Rectangular Box via CSS. But there is a border around that rectangle. How can I remove it? http://jsfiddle.net/allegrissimo123/LcfdA/

```
.divider{
    height: 10px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.divider:after{
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px; 
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #eaeaea transparent; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;     
}
```

Comment: Can't see. Which browser are you using? Also, send a screenshot.

Comment: maybe he is talking about the big border below the :after (which is the background of parent element). If true then just remove background property from .divider

Comment: I use Firefox. Here is a image. http://oi61.tinypic.com/11jm73p.jpg

Comment: Checked on all browsers i couldn't see any border there :/

Comment: Impossible to reproduce!

Comment: add "border-style: inset"  to .divider:after

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/kt1ud.jpg this is the ouput i got in firefox??  i dont see any border..

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

```
border-color: transparent transparent #eaeaea transparent; 
border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0) #eaeaea rgba(255,255,255,0);
```